# What is a minimal kernel configuration that boots with UEFI on aarch64?

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, uefi

I've been playing around with some [UEFI firmware](https://github.com/pftf/RPi4) I downloaded for Raspberry Pi, and I've also been trying to get the [Raspberry Pi Kernel](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) to boot with UEFI. So I simply ran `make -j4 bcm2711_defconfig` and enabled the options shown on the [Linux From Scratch page](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/11.3/postlfs/grub-setup.html) on booting with UEFI and ran `make -j4` to compile my kernel.
Once it finished, I ran `make -j4 dtbs modules` and `make -j4 dtbs_install modules_install install` to install my kernel. I found a file named `vmlinuz.efi` in `/boot` and thought this was a good sign.
Upon reboot, I entered the UEFI shell provided and typed in the following commands:

```
Shell> fs0:
FS0:\> vmlinuz.efi root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait ro
```

Instead of booting up (or getting a kernel panic), I got the following result:

```
Shell> fs0:
FS0:\> vmlinuz.efi root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait ro
EFI stub: Decompressing Linux Kernel...
EFI stub: Generating empty DTB
EFI stub: Exiting boot services...
EFI stub: ERROR: Exit boot services failed.
EFI stub: ERROR: Failed to update FDT and exit boot services
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my [.config file](https://wtools.io/code/dl/bKs8)